# Randomly generate user input

Tags: javascript, random, input

Im really new to coding, and i wanted to know if it was possible to randomly generate entries submitted by a user.

For example.
If the user was to enter 5 words,
Would they then be stored in a way that you would have a button to just click 'next' and randomly move through them.

Ive checked all around but cant seem to find anything,
Please help!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very abstract but the answer below details the following:

A user is able to save an infinite number of words.
A button is then able to randomly take one of these words and display it on the screen.

**preview**

https://jsfiddle.net/gwcq2qc9/1/

**html**

```
<input id="word"><button id="save">save</button>
<br><br>
<button id="show">show</button><br>
Random: <span id="output">...</span>
```

**javascript**

```
var words  = [];
var input  = document.getElementById('word');
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');
var showWordButton = document.getElementById('show');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  words.push(input.value);
  input.value = '';
}, false);

showWordButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  output.innerHTML = getRandomWord();
})

function getRandomWord () {
  return words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)]
}
```

Comment: Thats so great!
Thanks so much for your help, i really appreciate it.
Sorry about the vagueness of my question.
Im quite new to coding.

If i wanted them to input a few sentences,
is there a way to put a character limit in, is this possible.
also to display the answers so they came up 5 words per line?

Thanks again!

Comment: Also, can the answers be permanently saved, so you dont have to keep submitting them everytime youre on the website?